# When declaring data structure as its interface and then cast it does Java store somewhere the details

Tags: java, interface

I have seen in various place recommended that when using Collection or Lists or Hashes to declare them as the interface and then when instantiating use the specific structure you want.

For instance:

```
Map<K,V> map;
...
map = new LinkedHashMap<K,V>();
```

or

```
List<K> list;
...
list = new ArrayList<K>();
```

My question is, does Java "store the implementation details" somewhere.
The reason I am asking is that I have this class where I am using a HashMap. So I declared its member as a Map and when initializing it, based on some extra variable I initialize it as a HashMap with a certain size. I also have a getter.

Now in another class I have access to the class so when I need the map I just call the getter and get it. So I cast it to HashMap.

```
HashMap<K,V> hashMap = (HashMap) class.getMap();
for(Map.Entry<K,V> entry : hashMap.entrySet())
...
```

So does it remember what it is. If I decide that order matters to me and change it to use LinkedHashMap will it still iterate with the FIFO order. If I have to cast it to a certaing structure every time I use the class in other parts of my project, isn't it better to declare it as it is used.

Comment: `but foreach doesn't work for Map` - that's wrong

Comment: What does this have to do with C++?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to cast to a HashMap.

This works :

```
for (Map.Entry<K,V> entry : class.getMap().entrySet ())
```

Comment: Yeah, I corrected it. My question is that if when I built the map I used a LInkedHashMap to initialise, when later I get it and iterate will it keep the order that a LinkedHashMap has (first inserted, first out) or will it behave as a Map that doesn't necessarily keep the order

Comment: @AndreasAndreou It will behave according to the implementation that is being used. If you create a LinkedHashMap, it will remain a LinkedHashMap.

Comment: @pbabcdefp Thanks for the comment. I missed that. It's a good thing I included the other option :)

Comment: @AndreasAndreou: The interface in this case only says "Elements can be iterated". The implementation defines *how* this happens.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, does Java "store the implementation details"
>   somewhere.

Well, yes, of course it does. But that's just normal OOP. The type of the concrete class is known at runtime.

> I have to iterate the map but foreach doesn't work for Map.

What makes you think so? Yes, you *can* iterate a collection via its interface. **The whole mechanism would be entirely useless if you couldn't.** Of course, the code you provided does not compile because of your wrong use of the `class` keyword...

> So I cast it to HashMap.

Without knowing the details of your code, I am still quite sure that this is the wrong approach to your problem.

Comment: yeah, the class was just an unfortunate usage, wanted to say I call a class (I obviosuly don't use the keyword class) and as for the doesn't work, was in a rush. Wanted to say that for a Map or a HashMap when you iterate the order doesn't necessarily stay the same (mainly when a rehash occurs)

Comment: @AndreasAndreou: An interface does not do anything by itself. It does not iterate. It only specifies that implementations can iterate. Whether the static (i.e. known at compile-time) type of your `map` object is `Map` or `HashMap` does not matter. The dynamic type at run time is `HashMap` in any case, and it's `HashMap` which "does all the work".